# Dynamic Upload Folder For Jquery File Upload Widget

Tags: php, jquery, json, file, upload

My issue is regarding this - [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) which it great, bar the lack of support documentation and answer to THE most asked question it seems!

How do we define the upload folder, in upload.class.php dynamically?

At best, the answers that I have found to this question are 'murky' and so a clear cut answer would be brilliant.

So far I have this:

```
class UploadHandler
{

public $MY_PATH = "rootFolder/subFolder/anotherSubFolder";

 protected $options;
    function __construct($options=null) {


        $this->options = array( 
            'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
            'upload_dir' => $this->MY_PATH .'/',
            'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'.$this->MY_PATH .'/',
```

This works, but the problems start when I try to use `$variables` to define `$MY_PATH`:

```
public $MY_PATH = $rootFolder.'/'.$subFolder.'/'$anotherSubFolder;
```

Why does this not work... I just get errors (for no doubt an obvious reason to someone!).

So, how do I define `$MY_PATH` in the way I have described and then use it the result in `UploadHandler` class as required to allow the upload folders to be dynamic?

Note: I'm certain that my `$vars` have the correct values, I checked by echoing them out in my testing.

Comment: What errors, which echo's. From the docs about [property declarations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Declaring variables to properties is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

*sigh* .. ok, try

```
class UploadHandler {

  public $MY_PATH;

  protected $options; function __construct($options=null) {
    // make sure $rootFolder or any variable is known to the constructor scope, 
    // use globals etc.
    $this->MY_PATCH = $rootFolder.'/'.$subFolder.'/'$anotherSubFolder;
    $this->options = array( 
     'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
     'upload_dir' => $this->MY_PATH .'/',
     'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'.$this->MY_PATH .'/',
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm getting an error "undefined variable" along with others that come as a result I think. The vars that I'm trying to utilize are present in the document with correct data, these are the variables that I echoed out whilst checking that out, which I did just above the Uploader class in the document. So it must have something to do with declaring variables to properties as you say. I'll read up on that, like I say, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Please see my comment on `// make sure $rootFolder or any variable is known to the constructor scope, use globals etc`

Comment: Problem solve via another route. – Step 1: create two files in same directory as images folder and name index.php and upload.class.php. Step 2: inside files, I used require('original-upload.class.php'); and require('original-index.php'); Step 3: In the upload form, I set action attribute to my index.php in the root folder mentioned and all is well! This way, when I have to update the plugin over time, all of the dynamically created folders using the plugin in my system can be upgraded by updating two files. This method also negates the need to use variables when setting the image upload path.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me:

1- In the upload.class.php change:

```
$a = $_REQUEST["path"];

    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/'.$a.'/',
        'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'.$a.'/',
```

*So that you get the directory name by request*

2- Then there are three places where you should put your path variable so that you post it to upload.class.php whenever you request it.

a- In the form (default with id="fileupload") put an hidden input named path

```
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="whatever_you_want_the_path" id="fileuploadpth">
```

b- make an global javascript variable

```
var mypath = "whatever_you_want_the_path"
```

c- Add into Jquery File Uploader initialization

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({'formData' : { 'path' : mypath }});
```

d- In the js where existing files are loaded change the get url

```
$.getJSON(this.action
```

to

```
$.getJSON(this.action+'index.php?path='+ path
```

e- in the template on html change data-url for the delete button

```
 data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}
```

to

```
 data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}&path={%=path%}">
```

**P.S. Be careful when using this because this trick may lower the security of your application since directory name is stored in client side**